# sql join between two dates

Tags: sql, date, join

Let's say i have two tables:

**employees:**

```
Name    id    beg_eff_date    end_eff_date    group
Jack    101a  01-01-16        03-31-16        4
Jack    101a  04-01-16        12-31-99        3
```

**Sales**

```
emp_id    sale_amt    sale_date
101a      25          01-22-16
101a      28          04-10-16
```

my desired output:

```
emp_id    sale_amt    sale_date    name    group
101a      25          01-22-16     Jack    4
101a      28          04-10-16     Jack    3
```

This is the code I'm using, but it seems to not be working in at least one case (with my real dataset), so I want to be sure I'm writing correctly:

```
select sales.emp_id, sales.sale_amt, sales.sale_date, 
    emp.name, emp.group
from sales
inner join employees emp
    on sales.emp_id = emp.id
where sales.sale_date between emp.beg_eff_date and emp.end_eff_date
```

The goal here is to get the group number that the employee was in at the time of the sale.

Thanks a ton!

Comment: *... it seems to not be working in at least one case* which exact case?

Comment: The `sale_date`, `beg_eff_date` and `end_eff_date` datatype is varchar, those need to convert as `date`

Comment: This is an example table, I don't know how to upload the whole thing. But the error I'm seeing is the wrong group numbers being returned - In at least one case it is returning the employee's current group, rather than the group she was in at the time of the sale

Comment: You're doing something with dates, but I can't see any dates here

Comment: Can you give us an example of real data where a wrong group number is returned?   Including what number is being returned and what number should be returned?   I see nothing wrong with your current query, except possibly what @Arulkumar pointed out.

Comment: You don't need to upload the whole table, just a minimal example of the issue.

Comment: I see a value `12-31-99` for `end_eff_date` it mean `December 31, 2099` ? Hope it consider `December 31, 1999` only!

Comment: Just jumping in to agree with others. There is nothing wrong with your query (I would put that WHERE clause in the ON, but that's more of a preference really). This feels more like a data issue (dates stored as a string type instead of a date type, or data combinations that aren't shown here in the sample like overlapping date ranges and the like).

Comment: Is `12-31-99` interpreted as `2099-12-31` or as `1999-12-31`?  Why did you not learn from the Y2K fiasco?  (Oh, you weren't in the business back then — suffice to say, 2-digit years cause trouble!)

Comment: Just `cast` the `varchar` to `datetime` and try. Please execute the following query: `select sales.emp_id, sales.sale_amt, sales.sale_date, emp.name, emp.[group]
from sales
inner join employees emp
    on sales.emp_id = emp.id
where cast(sales.sale_date as datetime) between cast(emp.beg_eff_date as datetime) and cast(emp.end_eff_date as datetime);`

Comment: I think you are running into an issue because the id's you are joining on are the same on both tables. You need to have unique id's on the employee table. At least that is what I can tell just from looking at it.

Answer (score 0):

Your commentors appear to be on the right track.  Your `BETWEEN` clause seems to be working on text data, not date data.  You're going to have to force it into a date data-type for it to work.  You may want to consider changing your source tables to always use the date data-type for their dates.  Then you won't need to use the following mess every time you want to do date-math.  "This mess":

```
select sales.emp_id, sales.sale_amt, sales.sale_date, 
    emp.name, emp.group
from sales
inner join employees emp
    on sales.emp_id = emp.id
where CONVERT(Date, iif(RIGHT(sales.sale_date, 2) < 50, '20', '19') + RIGHT(sales.sale_date, 2) + '-' + LEFT(sales.sale_date, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(sales.sale_date, 4, 2)) 
between  
  CONVERT(Date, iif(RIGHT(emp.beg_eff_date, 2) < 50, '20', '19') + RIGHT(emp.beg_eff_date, 2) + '-' + LEFT(emp.beg_eff_date, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(emp.beg_eff_date, 4, 2)) 
and 
  CONVERT(Date, iif(RIGHT(emp.end_eff_date, 2) < 50, '20', '19') + RIGHT(emp.end_eff_date, 2) + '-' + LEFT(emp.end_eff_date, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(emp.end_eff_date, 4, 2))
```

Comment: PS.  This is written for MS SQL Server.  Is that what you're using?

Comment: Edit: fortgot some `'`'s around the 19s.  My bad.

Answer (score 0):

This is the type of effective date logic I used to use a while ago so pardon the old sql syntax:

```
select sales.emp_id, sales.sale_amt, sales.sale_date, 
    emp.name, emp.group
from sales, employees emp 
where sales.emp_id = emp.id
and emp.group in
  (select emp2.group 
   from employees emp2
   where emp2.emp_id = emp.emp_id
   and sales.sale_date between emp2.beg_eff_date and emp2.end_eff_date)
```

I'm assuming those eff_date columns are actual date types.